# Exposed sanitary tee as cleanout?

Tags: plumbing, drain, cleanout

If my sanitary tees (with an extension) are exposed through the finished wall, can I forgo adding a dedicated cleanout at the end of this long drain run?

If I ever need to snake this line, I can do it at either drain connections, behind washer/dryer or at kitchen sink.

Is this code compliant?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you're allowed to have that elbow between the cleanout opening and the stack. For what it's worth, I've never seen a clog in a properly installed PVC pipe beyond the sink trap. They're that slippery.

Comment: You need to be able to clean out the vent as well as the drain, so I'm dubious that this passes, without poring over code. A normal cleanout or two-way tee allows that, this would not. My cheat code is that the only place I go below 2" is right at the trap adapter. I'm also pretty sure the kitchen sink vent needs to go at 45 from above the san-tee, not up to the window and over. Vents must rise "vertically" which is actually defined as within 45 degrees of vertical) until 6" above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor (or served by the vent, depending on which exact code.)

Comment: Other than the special and defined case of island venting, of course, where you have to follow what's defined for that in your applicable code. Speaking of which, what IS your applicable plumbing code in your LAHJ?